# Using Ubuntu Git and msysgit to directly work with same files

Tags: git, ubuntu, windows-7-x64

I know that normally there are no problems using Git from different OSs to work with the same repositories, but I want to know if this particular scenario would be an exception to that. Do you see any problems working this way?

We have an Ubuntu server with several Git repositories on it. Git is installed on the server and sometimes people will SSH in to gain remote access and use Git that is installed on that server directly through the shell (yes I know that is weird and the standard would be to have a local cloned Git repository instead of using the remote Git installation).

On my Windows 7 workstation I am using WebDrive to map a directory from the Ubuntu server as a network drive on my computer even though my computer is on a completely different network. This works over SSH. I want to use the git installation on my Windows 7 computer to work with the files on this drive as if they were local. I will be doing things like cloning from, pulling from, and pushing to repositories that were created and continue to be used by the Git installation from the Ubuntu server.

I can't see any reason that this would create any problems that you would not normally run into with the standard use of Git, but I just wanted to make sure (I don't want to have a corrupt repository). Also, is there anything I should watch out for when working this way?

EDIT: My requirements just now changed. I will also need to do direct commits (in addition to pulls and pushes) using my msysgit to a repository that was created with the Ubuntu git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that when you are committing the line endings are `as is` or `unix-style` ( thought msysgit says the latter is the recommended for cross-platform projects ) This is one of the screens that you see while installing msysgit:

[image]

http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/files/2011/03/msysgit_install8_69176BC0.png

You can also easily see / change this from Git Extensions settings ( if you are using it ) but it is about setting `core.autocrlf` to `false` or `input`

Other thing to ensure is that you are using similar versions of git / msysgit on both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Should both versions of git be set up this way, or is this only an option for msysgit? Also did you see my latest requirement (there is an edit at the end of my question)? Thanks.

Comment: @INTPnerd - only on msysgit side. Yeah that is something I do. ( I have a single repo on a drive in my machine that I work from on both Windows and Ubuntu. Which is believe almost same as what you want )

Comment: I'd add that if you're have `core.autocrlf` set to `false` (as I'd generally recommend) you need to use tools that cope with Unix-style as well as DOS-style line endings.